# Why do we have to put the range of iteration of for loop as range(0,len(list)), instead of range( 0,len(list)-1 )

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def print_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        print x[i]
        print i

print_list(n)
```

I thought since the program is iterating through the index, having the range as len(list) would be out of range. However, this is apparently the correct way, and I'm not really sure why. Can somebody explain?

Comment: Hello, please write your code, do'nt share images

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range - `range` isn't inclusive of the `stop` value.

Comment: python's  `range` gets elements as `[a,b,c,d...)` which menas the last element won't make part of it

Answer (score 0):

The range() function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 by default, and increments by 1 (by default), and stops when it reaches the specified number.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Comment: add reference to the range() function in your answer

Comment: It stops when it reaches the specified number

Comment: OP is asking on why last number is "not used"

Comment: @John123 think of it like you are specifying the number of elements as the parameter. range(3) will return 0,1,2 , i.e. 3 elements. It doesn't return the number specified in the parameter.